# What is the route within a local network?

Tags: networking

The IP addr of my `wlan1` is `192.168.1.3`.

```
$ netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan1
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan1
```

Does the second entry in the table mean that if the destination is in the same local network as `wlan1`, the datagram isn't forwarded to a gateway (`*` for `Gateway`)?

What  is the route for a datagram from `wlan1` to an IP address in `192.168.1.0/24`?

What does `UG` mean under `Flags`?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the `*` entry in the `Gateway` column means that the packet is kept in the local network.

In the `Flags` column the `U` signifies that the route is up, while the `G` signifies that the route is to a gateway.

Other options which can appear under in the `Flags` column are:

```
U : This flag signifies that the route is up
G : This flag signifies that the route is to a gateway. If this flag is not present then we can say that the route is to a directly connected destination
H : This flag signifies that the route is to a host which means that the destination is a complete host address. If this flag is not present then it can be assumed that the route is to a network and destination would be a network address.
D : This flag signifies that this route is created by a redirect.
M : This flag signifies that this route is modified by a redirect.
```

Source: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/route-flags/

Comment: Thanks. About your first sentence for gateway `*` i.e. `0.0.0.0`, there seemed to be a different reply from http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30669/discussion-between-pl-rock-and-tim "if any network shows gateway 0.0.0.0 means default gateway will use(generally default gatway is first line of output ) ". Is what you said contrary to what he said?

Comment: I believe the poster there is mistaken. The `*` / `0.0.0.0` address which represents a non-existing destination. Your device will not know where to send this packet other than to the local network. This is what is documented in the man page for `route`. http://linux.die.net/man/8/route `The gateway address or '*' if none set.`